# send image and form data in phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

have seen some online examples buy am confused of how to send Image and form data (text) to a server via phonegap ajax.

had used the file input tag ut it seems that this tag is not supported for phonegap. the current code is for simple ajax (via jquery) to send data and image file from the file input tag.

kindly assist withn a basic example of how to send for example the following along with an image.

```
Key : name  -- value : abc
image key 'logo'
```

any assistance appreciated

Comment: `<input type="file">` is not supported on Chromium in Android 4.4, you can see this with the Chrome browser even.

Comment: thank you for the comment. yes after testing on emulator, it was realized that file input is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make use of Fileupload available in cordova file [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) and you can send your parameter along with it

```
var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. ut how can we send additional parameter as key-value

Comment: how would we define its keys?

Comment: ok . that was a confusing part (for me :) ) . . will try and inform asap .. thank you

Comment: Kool and server side you can get in formcollection

Comment: yes. that is already set.. as said the code is working file when used wth jquery and file input tag but phonegap doesnt seem to support file input tag

Comment: input file is not supported in android

Comment: am using cordova 2.9. the code doesnt seem to invoke anything. is there any configuration required ?